# 2- dimensional parameter

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\begin{align}
 x_1 &+ 4x_2 − 3x_3 + 2x_4 = 0 \\ 
 2x_1 &+ 7x_2 − 4x_3 + 4x_4 = 0 \\
 −x_1 &+ ax_2 + 5x_3 − 2x_4 = 0 \\ 
3x_1 &+ 10x_2 − 5x_3 + (a^2 + 4a + 1)x_4 = 0\\
\end{align}$$

For which value of $a$ is the answer 2-dimensional (a.k.a. 2 parameters)? Define in this case, the set of solutions.

I've calculated the values for a: $a=1$ or $a=-5$, but how do i find the $2$ parameters and what do i have to answer? I don't really understand what kind of answer they want

Comment: Without LaTeX the mathematics in this post are extremely hard to understand...

Comment: @DaphneS: What if you use Gaussian Elimination for each value of $a$ that you found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a homogeneous system; let's do Gaussian elimination on its matrix:
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 4 & −3 & 2 \\ 
 2 & 7 & −4 & 4 \\
-1 & a &  5 & −2 \\ 
 3 & 10& -5 & a^2 + 4a + 1
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 4 & −3 & 2 \\ 
 0 & -1 & 2 & 0 \\
 0 & a+4 & 2 & 0 \\ 
 0 & -2& 4 & a^2 + 4a -5
\end{bmatrix}
\\
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 4 & −3 & 2 \\ 
 0 & 1 & -2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 2a+10 & 0 \\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & a^2 + 4a -5
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
If $a\ne-5$, the rank of the matrix is at least $3$, so the null space can't have dimension $2$. If $a=-5$, the matrix has indeed rank $2$. The matrix, in this case, becomes
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 4 & −3 & 2 \\ 
 0 & 1 & -2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 5 & 2 \\ 
 0 & 1 & -2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and the system becomes
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1=-5x_3-2x_4\\x_2=2x_3
\end{cases}
$$
and you can write the solution vector as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-5h-2k\\
2h\\
h\\
k
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $h$ and $k$ are arbitrary.

If $a=1$, then the rank is $3$, so the solutions depend only on one parameter. If $a\ne-5$ and $a\ne1$, there is only one solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have four linear equations for four unknowns (x1,x2,x3,x4). Consider solving these equations; the solutions will be functions of parameter "a". Can you continue with this ?

Answer (score 0):

For any value of a (except -5 or 1), all four unknowns evaluate to zero; for the two exceptions, the unknowns evaluate to the indeterminate form 0/0.

Comment: Using only the determinant, you can't discriminate between ranks, you only know when the rank is $4$ or less than $4$.